# How to check Rubi version number in use?

Tags: packages, rubi

On my Mathematica 11.2 Windows system I have Rubi version 4.15 installed manually and version 4.16 installed with the paclet installation procedure. So these two versions reside in totally different places. When I have loaded Rubi either from the notebook by

```
Get["Rubi`"]
```

or as autoload in one of my init.m files by

```
DeclarePackage["Rubi`",{"Int"}]
```

how can I check which version of Rubi I have actually loaded in the notebook?

Comment: `$RubiVersion` is defined in V4.16.1.0.  Does it exist in 4.15?

Comment: @Michael, after having removed the old version, I can load 4.16 and the version command works. So it is not available in 4.15. Thanks a lot for your hint!